# Livewire pass id for update

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How can I pass the id from list and update that item in database?

## Code

```
<button class="acceptOrder btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:click="$emit('orderAccepted', {{$order->id}})">Accept order</button>

protected $listeners = ['acceptOrder'];

public function acceptOrder(Order $order)
{
  $order->update(['accepted' => true]);
}
```

## Error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: why ur using $emit you can direct call function in on click right ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Idk I just followed documentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly call function in `wire:click()`

try this

```php
<button class="acceptOrder btn btn-sm btn-success" wire:click="orderAccepted('{{ $order->id }}')">Accept order</button>
```

then in compoenent

```php
public function orderAccepted(Order $order)
{
  $order->update(['accepted' => true]);
}
```

ref link https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions

Comment: `VM48446:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: for search pagination

Comment: same error, however I found a solution for the error,  `wire:click="orderAccepted('{{ $order->id }}')"` but it returns `Unable to call component method. Public method [orderAccepted] not found on component: [orders]`

Comment: fixed that as well it was function name should be `orderAccepted`

Comment: `$emit` we use if need to transfer data on component to another component

Comment: change your code `wire:click...` to the one i commented and i'm more than happy to accept it